# Rig controls appear above bones

Tags: rigging, rigify

[image: Controls out of place?]

When I generate the rig using rigify the controls for the arms and head move up and out of place. Is this just for display or has something gone wrong? I did recalculate bones to front view, not sure if that matters, thanks!

Comment: Did you reset the scale of both the armature and model in Object mode using ALT - S before generating the rig?

Comment: John Eason I believe i just scaled using S in Edit mode the first time. i redid the rig on a dup file and it's worked. Is ALT-S in object mode the way to go? Thanks

Comment: Yes. Look at the object's scale settings in Object mode for both armature and mesh. If any of them aren't set to zero before you generate the rig you're likely to have problems. You should get the overall scale of the armature roughly correct in Object mode before you tweak the settings in edit mode. Then go back to Object mode and use ALT S before hitting the Generate button.